# Windows patching on SharePoint servers

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, patching

Often when Windows patching is done on SharePoint servers, i see even SharePoint security patches get installed on it. Post that my central admin page shows "Patching required".

Does the SharePoint patching should always be followed by windows OS patching?

Comment: Run sp config wizard

Comment: Is that a must after every windows patching activity? Few security updates are part of SharePoint CU`s. If we run PS Config wizard, that will update DB, without complete SP CU updates, if i run PS Config, will that wont effect in  any way?

Comment: yes, run sp config wizar after each install,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's really the other way around. First you update Windows Server (both the SQL Server and Windows Server which hosts SharePoint) using Windows Updates. When this is done, update SharePoint, starting with application servers. Make sure the PSCONFIG runs successfully before moving on to the next server.

See: [Tips for Patching SharePoint 2013](https://www.concurrency.com/blog/march-2016/tips-for-patching-sharepoint-2013)

Comment: Thank you Benny. Just want to be sure, should we run PS Config after installing SP CU on all servers or on one server? Also, want to understand, is must to install SP updates as well post Windows updates or this can be done separate timelines?

Comment: @AchieverSP You patch one server at a time and run PSCONFIG after each install, to be safe. Windows Patches and SharePoint Patches doesn't rely on each other, so you can run them on different times. Start by Windows Patching, and when you're done and have the time - begin SharePoint patching.

Answer (score 1):

as it is already answered, i want to add two cents. Please make sure following things.

- Dont enabled automatic updates on the SharePoint, if you do then make sure SharePoint updates unchecked from it. SharePoint required special steps in order to install the SP patches. If we dont aware that windows update installed SharePoint patches as well and we never run the config wizard, couple of days later we will see unexpected errors in the farm.
- Installation of SharePoint updates required a down time as it will reset IIS on farm several times unless you have HA farms.
- We have a process in place, Disabled the windows auto update and install windows update manually.
- Same thing with SharePoint updates, we schedule a downtime and install it Manually. We have to run the SharePoint Config wizard on the every server in the farm after SharePoint updates installed.